# How can I check one value against another value in my Google Sheet and then query properties of the cell with the matching value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I want to check values from a JSON URL against values within a defined range in my Google Sheet.

Should there be a match, I would like to query the properties of the cell containing the matching value (its row, its column, etc.)

How can I do this within Google Apps Script?

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you provide some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: [Here's some sample data.](http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random) [Here's a spreadsheet containing some of the phrases found through that webhook.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g2U8CQT8ukqp6e5slSfhmVKih8UZ1WiUmzb1c-Gx0ug/edit?usp=sharing) I've tried accomplishing my question through Zapier integrations, but found it too limited since it can't go on a cell-by-cell basis. The desired result would be to match the phrases from the JSON to the sheet and then use the row and column of the matching cell to help define to what cell to write/append new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Got to my answer myself.

```js
var i = 0;

// Bringing in the data from the third-party into Google Sheets.
var groupJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch('<ANY-JSON-URL>');
var groupObjectRaw = JSON.parse(groupJSON);
//  var groupObject = groupObjectRaw[0]; <--optional, for my use only

var membersGroupForm = groupObject.data['member'];
var projectsGroupForm = groupObject.data['project'];
var hoursGroupForm = groupObject.data['hours worked'];

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Details');

var membersRange = ss.getRange('Details!A:A');
var membersSheet = membersRange.getValues();

var projectsRange = ss.getRange('Details!1:1');
var projectsSheet = projectsRange.getValues();

function getRowNumber() {
  for (i; i < membersSheet.length; i++) {
    if (membersSheet[i][0] == membersGroupForm) {
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
}

var rowNumber = getRowNumber(i, membersSheet, membersGroupForm);
Logger.log(rowNumber);

function getColumnNumber() {
  for (var row in projectsSheet) {
    for (var col in projectsSheet[row]) {
      if (projectsSheet[row][col] == projectsGroupForm) {
        return parseInt(col) + 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

var columnNumber = getColumnNumber(projectsSheet, projectsGroupForm);
Logger.log(columnNumber);

var cell = ss.getRange(rowNumber, columnNumber);
cell.setValue(hoursGroupForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know about Spreadsheet operations in Apps Script can be found in [Overview and SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). You can start from there. For example, the methods to query properties like row and col are [getRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow()) and [getColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getColumn())